# Why does Android Studio download the same gradle binary regularly?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

This happens almost everyday. I get downloading it for new projects, maybe, but this happens for the same project over and over. What's going on ?

Here's my Android Studio version :

[image]

What's weird is that my Gradle version is set to `7.1.1` in my `build.gradle` file.